# Nextjs Suspense won't work with fetch api but with new promise timeout work perfectly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-suspense

Next.js doesn't work, where I try take data using fetch Api but won't display suspense fallback but when I write new promise with setTimeout it's work perfectly. As I know fetch API is based on promises, so why without adding additional line of code with promise suspense won't work?

Example:

```
interface Post {
    userId: number,
    id: number,
    title: string,
    body: string
}


async function getPosts() {
    const posts: any = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(res => res.json()).catch(res => new Error('Failed to fetch data'));
    // await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
    return posts;
}

async function View() {
    const posts: Post[] = await getPosts();

    
    return (
        <main>
            {posts && posts.map((post: Post) => {
              return <li>{post.title}</li>  
            })}
        </main>
    )
}

export default View
```

Parent component:

```
import { Suspense } from "react"
import Loading from "./loading"
import View from '../../components/View';



const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
            <View />
        </Suspense>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard
```

Try find specified information but still is confusing to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue may be related to the handling of promises. There is no need to use setTimeout to manage promises. If you handle promises using async/await, the code waits until data is received into any variable. When waiting for data, the issue might be associated with the fact that Suspense is currently not supported for server-side rendering (SSR) in Next.js. Suspense is primarily designed for use with React's concurrent mode, which is not fully compatible with server rendering.

**1. Use useEffect to Fetch Data which is common method to fetch data after component mounted**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

async function getPosts() {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  const posts = await response.json();
  return posts;
}

function View() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getPosts().then((data) => setPosts(data));
  }, []);

  return (
    <main>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>
      ))}
    </main>
  );
}

export default View;
```

*****"if you are using in SSR then use 'use client' for it .*****

**2. Ensure that Fallback Component `<Loading />` component is working correctly and doesn't have any issues that could prevent it from being displayed.**

Document refer [React Suspense](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense)

**3. If You are working on SSR ( Server side Rendering ) Nextjs Then try to use `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps` for fetching data.**

```
import View from '../components/View';

const Dashboard = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <View posts={posts} />
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  const posts = await response.json();

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
  };
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: THis is answer that I expected. Thanks for help! <3